# How to do qcut in polars exactly similar as pandas?

Tags: python, python-polars

The qcut in polars is not the same as pandas, thus I want to have those two features for my own qcut. But I do not know how to do the null check in qcut, and drop duplicates in qcut(I know there is a parameter in qcut as `allow_duplicates`, but it's not working).

### qcut for duplicate breakpoints

What I have done:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({'group': ['a'] * 5 + ['b'] * 5,'value': [1] * 5 + [2] * 5})
df.with_columns(q=pl.col("value").qcut(2, allow_duplicates=False).over('group'))
```

I got:

```
| g   | x   | q   |
|-----|-----|-----|
| str| i64 | cat |
| "a"| 1   | (-inf, 1] |
| "a"| 1   | (-inf, 1] |
| "a"| 1   | (-inf, 1] |
| "a"| 1   | (-inf, 1] |
| "a"| 1   | (-inf, 1] |
| "b"| 2   | (-inf, 2] |
| "b"| 2   | (-inf, 2] |
| "b"| 2   | (-inf, 2] |
| "b"| 2   | (-inf, 2] |
| "b"| 2   | (-inf, 2] |
```

Which should be:

```
group   
a      0   NaN
       1   NaN
       2   NaN
       3   NaN
       4   NaN
b      5   NaN
       6   NaN
       7   NaN
       8   NaN
       9   NaN
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

### qcut for Null values

When I set the values to be Nans, like:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({'group': ['a'] * 5 + ['b'] * 5,'value': [None] * 5 + [2] * 5})
df.with_columns(q=pl.col("value").qcut(2, allow_duplicates=False).over('group'))
```

I got errors:

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', /home/runner/work/polars/polars/crates/polars-ops/src/series/ops/cut.rs:112:14
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PanicException                            Traceback (most recent call last)
   7632         .with_columns(*exprs, **named_exprs)
   7633         .collect(no_optimization=True)
   7634     )

File ~/test/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/utils/deprecation.py:93, in deprecate_renamed_parameter..decorate..wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     88 @wraps(function)
     89 def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
     90     _rename_keyword_argument(
     91         old_name, new_name, kwargs, function.__name__, version
---> 93     return function(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/test/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/lazyframe/frame.py:1695, in LazyFrame.collect(self, type_coercion, predicate_pushdown, projection_pushdown, simplify_expression, no_optimization, slice_pushdown, comm_subplan_elim, comm_subexpr_elim, streaming)
   1683     comm_subplan_elim = False
   1685 ldf = self._ldf.optimization_toggle(
   1686     type_coercion,
   1687     predicate_pushdown,
   (...)
   1693     streaming,
   1694 )
-> 1695 return wrap_df(ldf.collect())

PanicException: called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value
```

What I want:
The corresponding value should be Null too.

THANK YOU!

```
--------Version info---------
Polars:              0.18.15
Index type:          UInt32
Platform:            Linux-5.3.0-28-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.27
Python:              3.9.16 (main, Mar  8 2023, 14:00:05) 
[GCC 11.2.0]

----Optional dependencies----
adbc_driver_sqlite:  <not installed>
cloudpickle:         <not installed>
connectorx:          <not installed>
deltalake:           <not installed>
fsspec:              <not installed>
matplotlib:          3.7.2
numpy:               1.24.4
pandas:              2.0.3
pyarrow:             12.0.1
pydantic:            <not installed>
sqlalchemy:          <not installed>
xlsx2csv:            <not installed>
xlsxwriter:          <not installed>
```